# How to close with Seleniun an add that is in other body tag than the principal one?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, web-scraping, bots

[image]I am Trying to download the table in the following link https://es.investing.com/economic-calendar/manufacturing-pmi-202 using Selenium, there is a button called "Show more" that I need to click until it dissapears so I can get the complete data. But after the first click an youtube add appears at the  bottom left  and my bot get stuck. If I delete the add everything works, but when I try to delete the add with Selenium I fail because the add is not in the first body tag, is in other one. What can I do?

Here is the error when my bot get stuck:

selenium.common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted: Element ... is not clickable at point (326, 874). Other element would receive the click: 
(Session info: chrome=83.0.4103.106)

I upload an image with the HTML, where the blue line is the one of the ad.

Finally, this is my code:

```
while  i< 600:
        try:        
            driver.find_element_by_id('showMoreHistory{n}'.format(n=n)).click() #hago click n-veces para poder ver los datos historicos
            i = i + 1
        except: 
            driver.find_element_by_id('closeBtn').click()
            i = i +1
```

Comment: You can provide the `Html` when the ad is present in your post.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't recreate your problem... Could you provide a bit more information?

Comment: Sory, it was my fault. Now I upload more information.

Answer (score 0):

After reading the HTMl again I discover that de body tag is inside a div, so I change my code to delete that div and now is working.

This is my new code:

```
while  i< 600:
            try:        
                driver.find_element_by_id('showMoreHistory{n}'.format(n=n)).click() #hago click n-veces para poder ver los datos historicos
                i = i + 1
            except: 
                if(not error):  
                    element = driver.find_element_by_id('primis_container_div')
                    driver.execute_script("""var element = arguments[0];element.parentNode.removeChild(element);""", element)
                    error = True
                i = i +1
```